# Lock variable changes in Ionic3/Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an object which I change on a provider class in ionic 3. This object is accessible from other methods/pages/components. Is there a way to set a lock on this object so when I am changing it in one method, it will not be changed from other areas.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to read up on Typescript `readonly` properties. A `readonly` property can only be set during initialization or by a constructor. Check out this link for more information:

https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/10/31/typescript-2-0-read-only-properties

**Updated in response to the comment below:**

To create a lock, why not use simple boolean? If you have access to your property from multiple places then you would also have access to the boolean from multiple places. So you could do this, for example:

```
my_property: any;
can_set = false;

first_method() {
  if(this.can_set) {
    this.can_set = false;  
    // some code
    my_property = something;
  }
  this.can_set = true;
}

second_method() {
  if(this.can_set) {
    this.can_set = false;  
    // some code
    my_property = something;
  }
  this.can_set = true;
}
```

If the set happens in a callback then unlock the boolean in that callback.

Comment: Sorry but `readonly ` cannot resolve it. the properties will be changed multiple times. I am trying to figure out a way when method A() is changing object X, Method B() should not be able to change it. Also, the code in method B() will wait until the lock of X is free and then proceed with changes. Found something similar but can not use in in Ionic3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/threaded-lock

Comment: Sorry but still one concept is not clear. Let say `first_method()` is in between and `this.can_set = false`. `second_method()` will just go and check that change is not allowed and come back. It will not wait for the first method to finish, release the lock and then do its job. Am I missing something?

Comment: It can't happen unless you have the lock inside an asynchronous function. Typescript is, line by line,  synchronous. In other words,  if the code I provided was alone then the scenario you described isn't possible. If,  however, you set `can_set = true` and then do something like a server call before changing it then you could expose the variable to unwanted mutations.